# How to migrate 'current' mysql timestamp value to postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I have Mysql DB that contains
table 'tariff' with field

```
start_date DATETIME DEFAULT (current_timestamp() + interval 10 year),
```

And when I try to migrate database to postgreSQL using pgloader i get error

ERROR Database error 0A000: value "current" for datetime does not supported any more
QUERY: CRE ATE   TABLE yamalkernel.tariff
2021-10-06T09:51:25.248000+03:00 FATAL Failed to create the schema, see above

I run pgloader this way

$ pgloader scenario.load

$ cat scenario.load

```
LOAD DATABASE
FROM mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1/database1
INTO postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/database2;
```

Comment: Advice from pgloader author https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "tell" pgLoader to convert the problem field ("`start_date`") of the "`tariff`" table (in the "`CAST`" section), for example as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF > file.load
LOAD DATABASE
FROM mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1/database1
INTO postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/database2
CAST column tariff.start_date to "timestamptz DEFAULT now() + interval '10 year'" drop default;
EOF

pgloader -v file.load
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several errors in that code:

- use `timestamp` instead of `datetime`
- use `current_timestamp` instead of `current_timestamp()`
- the interval value needs to be enclosed in single quotes

So you need to use:

```
start_date timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp + interval '10 year'
```